# ember.js add child views

Tags: view, ember.js

I have the following code snippet:

```
App.TripLegView = Em.View.extend({
     transportMeanType: null,
     transportMeanTypeChanged: function  () {
          this.carView = App.CarView.create();
          var childView = this.createChildView(this.carView );
          this.get('childViews').pushObject(childView);
     }
}).observes('transportMeanType'),

App.CarView = Em.View.extend();
```

However when i debug the above code, the child view does not seem to be added to the childViews array.

Can anyone explain how to correctly add child views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it seems you are misusing the `observes()`, it should be defined on the function.
If you want to manipulate childviews, I think you should use [Ember.ContainerView](http://docs.emberjs.com/#doc=Ember.ContainerView&src=false)

Your code would be like this:

```
App.CarView = Em.View.extend();

App.TripLegView = Em.ContainerView.extend({
  transportMeanType: null,

  transportMeanTypeChanged: function  () {
    this.carView = App.CarView.create();
    var childView = this.createChildView(this.carView );
    this.get('childViews').pushObject(childView);
  }.observes('transportMeanType')
});
```

If it doesn't work, please post a jsfiddle to give an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i found out that you can'a add child to an instance of Em.View, since they are added during the rendering process. However, i would like to ask you about the observes() function. Why do you say that i misusing it. I following the official documentation. [link](http://emberjs.com/documentation/#toc_observers)

Comment: If you look closely, you can see you were putting it on the TrippleLegView, not on the transportMeanTypeChanged. Perhaps it was just a mistake in your question, not in your code.